# Whatis the correct phrase and why?

Tags: phrases

Which is the correct phase and why: I will arrive at 11:00 Am in Dallas or I will arrive in Dallas at 11:00 AM.

Comment: A.M. but never Am. Otherwise either is acceptable.

Comment: I am asking about the position in the phrase of the place and time. Which comes first the location or the time? Thank you in advance

Comment: Another possibility is *into*. See e.g. *[Difference between “at” and “in” when specifying location](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87306)*, *[When do we use “arrive at” versus “arrive in”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20768)* and *[Is it correct to say “We will be arriving into <station>”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154721)* among others.

Comment: OP: "Which comes first the location or the time?" Whatever's important. But it's not really important, place and time versus time and place.

Comment: It should be "At 11:00 AM I will arrive in Dallas."  Or as Yoda would say, "Arrive in Dallas at 11:00 AM I will."  (Seriously, it doesn't matter.  There is no ambiguity and and no semantic problem with either of the OP's options.)

Answer (score 2):

Both work equally well. There is no implicit difference in meaning or emphasis between the two.